# Как полностью удалить ячейку в mysql с помощью C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Я соединил бд с си шарпом и у меня есть функция удаления:

```
using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    mysqlCon.Open();
    MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("DeleteById", mysqlCon);
    mySqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_id", Id);
    mySqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Deleted");
    Clear();
    GridFill();
}
```

где `DeleteByID` это процедура удаления строки из mysql:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `DeleteByID`(
_id INT
)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM servicetype
    WHERE `idТип услуги` = _id;
END
```

но она удаляет просто данные а не полностью строку, т. е если у меня есть id от 1 до 6 и я удалю 1 и 5 id то получится вот это:
Как сделать так чтобы строчки полностью удалялись и сохранялась нумерация?
(т.е чтобы стало от 1 до 4 в конкретном примере)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Желание менять id записи, а вместе с ней нумерацию строк, нужно выдавливать из себя как раболепство из души. Айдишник задан при вставке. Точка. Оставьте его в покое. Нужна нумерация с 1 до 4 - делайте это в том месте, где выводите данные юзеру. / А главное, подумайте, что будет в многопользовательском окружении, когда несколько клиентов будут читать, писать и менять данные - как в этом случае менять ключ (id) без багов, локов и т. п.

Comment: То, что отображается запись из NULL-ов, не значит, что запись не удалена. Скорее всего это косяк интерфейса. Перезапустите его и проверьте, присутствует ли проблемная запись. Ещё лучше - проверить запросом в консольном клиенте. *т.е чтобы стало от 1 до 4* Нужна нумерация - создайте для неё отдельное поле. А автоинкремент не трогайте - он не для Вас, а для внешних ключей.

Comment: Это потому, что вы воспользовались мастером VS по созданию строготипизированного `DataSet` с привязкой к `DataGridView`, и в методе по удалению записи не используете необходимый, уже созданный для вас мастером, `DataAdapter`, а вместо этого напрямую работаете с БД минуя этот адаптер.